# combine multiple figures into one

Tags: r, plot

I would like to combine 2 pie charts and 3 box plots into one figure. I want 2 pie charts in the top and 3 box plots in the bottom. I get 2 pie charts and one box plot in the first row when I used `par(mfrow=c(2,3))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use layout

like

```
layout(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), nrow = 2, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE))
plot(1,main=1,ylab="A")
plot(2,main=2,ylab="B")
plot(3,main=3,ylab="C")
plot(4,main=4,ylab="D")
plot(5,main=5,ylab="E")
```

[image]

## Note

Here you need to create different size plot, you need divide your layout matrix on smallest part ( here it is 1/6 of plot)

You need such matrix (where different number- different plots)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2
[2,]    3    3    4    4    5    5
```

or `matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), nrow = 2, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: hmm.. what do you mean? can you explaim a bit more?

Comment: I would like to denote the first plot as 'A', second plot as 'B'   and third plot as 'C' etc..

Comment: Title of plot ( edit `main=` of plot)? or something else?

Comment: not title. figure numbering on the left side  of each figure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [grid](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/grid.html) concept in R to plot multiple figure into one row or rows and columns, please check the following for reference:

```
plot(1:3)
grid(NA, 5, lwd = 2) # grid only in y-direction

## maybe change the desired number of tick marks:  par(lab = c(mx, my, 7))
op <- par(mfcol = 1:2)
with(iris,
     {
     plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = as.integer(Species),
          xlim = c(4, 8), ylim = c(2, 4.5), panel.first = grid(),
          main = "with(iris,  plot(...., panel.first = grid(), ..) )")
     plot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = as.integer(Species),
          panel.first = grid(3, lty = 1, lwd = 2),
          main = "... panel.first = grid(3, lty = 1, lwd = 2), ..")
     }
    )
par(op)
```

[image: MULTIPLE-FIGURES-IN-ONE-ROW]